# Reactive form validation on blur of input field for Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using formControl validation to validate the input fields like required, minlength, email etc.

"valueChanges" works perfectly for me, but i want to use validation on blur of the input field.I want this because email validation using validators is not quite user friendly as user start typing the email address and until user completes the email address, validation error pop ups. so i want to do email validation on blur of the input email address.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `updateOn` was added in 5.0.0-beta.3 (2017-08-09) https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-8

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the valueChanges observable to perform your own validation. Instead, create your own custom validators and assign them to their formControls. Thus according the validators, your controls will always be valid/invalid, but within your template, with the help of the ngIf directive you will be able to show the error messages once the control is invalid and also dirty or touched.

xxx.component.html

`<input type="text" formControlName="email">
 <div *ngIf="form.get('email').errors?.required">The email is required</div>
 <div *ngIf="form.get('email').errors?.email">The email is invalid</div>`